# How to find latest compatible firebase library versions for android

Tags: android, firebase

I am using firebase in my android app. I have added `firebase-messaging`, `firebase-database`, `firebase-auth`, and `firebase-storage` libraries to my `build.gradle`.

When a new version of these libraries is available, Android Studio suggests to update the version to the new one.

But, the problem is that the latest versions of these four firebase libraries are not the same. Following were the versions when I last updated them to the latest version

[image: firebase versions]

My question is, if I update the firebase libraries to the latest versions available at a certain time, are they compatible with each other? Is it OK to update the library versions to the latest without doing any further investigations about the version compatibility?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest versions of everything should be compatible with each other.  You can see them all [listed in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#available_libraries).  The Play services gradle plugin will check to see if there are any possible incompatibilities between versions.

Answer (score 0):

Line with yellow highlight you can see warning, they describes the latest library, and yes when firebase firm put library for end developers they also consider the old version features and other stuff, means they doesn't remove all features but they includes new features with new one version, so that is ok and no need to worry about updating a new version of firebase libraries.